# Micro Focus Net Express 5.1 COBOL project - source code search

Tags: cobol, microfocus

Please I have project in Micro Focus Net Express 5.1 IDE. As you can see in picture below in browse window I have list of source codes in project. Is there any possibility to sort this list alphabetically or search in it? When I select root (project name) I got only message 'COBOL information file cannot be opened - please recompile'. But after recompile is still same. Normally in right pane you can see list of variables and sections used in program.
[image]

Comment: I don't know this IDE but suggest you explain *why* you want to do this in *that* IDE (instead of using `grep`, `findstr` or even something like `Notepad++`or `Eclipse`?